# How to pass a generic interface to a method where it is reified?

Tags: java, generics, reification

I have a generic interface

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
    T method(T input);
}
```

and a couple of implementations of it, via ordinary classes like

```
public class MyClass<T> implements MyInterface<T> {
    @Override
    public T method(T input) {
        T output = input; // whatever
        return output;
    }
}
```

and anonymous classes (see below). Now I want to test these implementations:

```
class TestClass1 {
    // ...
}

class TestClass2 {
    final int n;
    final String s;

    TestClass2(int n, String s) {
        this.n = n;
        this.s = s;
    }
    // ...
}

public class TestGenericImplementation {
    private static <T> void makeTest(T testObject, MyInterface<T> impl) {
        T output = impl.method(testObject);
        if (output == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        // verify output further
    }

    // Question 1. How to specify the parameter here properly?
    public static void testImplementation(MyInterface impl) {
        // Question 2. How to avoid compiler warning about unchecked cast below?

        // Doesn't work if impl is of type MyInterface<?> above
        makeTest(new TestClass1(), impl);
        makeTest(new TestClass2(1, "ABC"), impl); 

        // Ugly typecasts. Compiler complains.
        makeTest(new TestClass1(), (MyInterface<TestClass1>) impl);  
        makeTest(new TestClass2(1, "ABC"), (MyInterface<TestClass2>) impl); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Question 3. How to pass the interface argument here?

        // Works but issues compiler warning about raw type
        testImplementation(new MyClass());
        testImplementation(new MyInterface() {
            @Override
            public Object method(Object input) {
                return null; // whatever
            }
        });

        // Looks ugly
        testImplementation(new MyClass<Object>()); 
        testImplementation(new MyInterface<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object method(Object input) {
                return null;
            }
        });

        /* Diamond operator appeared only in Java 7,
         * while generics were introduced in Java 5.
         * What was the recommended way to solve this problem between 2004 and 2011?
         * Besides that, this doesn't work for anonymous classes.
         */
        testImplementation(new MyClass<>()); 
        testImplementation(new MyInterface<>() { // Doesn't work
            @Override
            public Object method(Object input) {
                return null;
            }
        });

        testImplementation(x -> x); // Lambda exprssions are for simple cases only
    }
}
```

The problem is that compiler is issuing a series of errors and warnings due to transition from a generic interface to its reified versions (those I need to use with the concrete classes `TestClass1` and `TestClass2` in place of the generic type variable `T`). Is it possible to avoid these warnings completely? If not (i.e. if they can only be suppressed), are there any pitfalls arising from this?

Comment: Generics in Java are never reified. What do you mean?

Comment: @Michael I meant transition from `T` to `TestClass1` and `TestClass2` in `testImplementation()`. If *reify* is a wrong term here, please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<T> void makeTest(T testObject, Test.MyInterface<T> impl)
```

expects T to be the same for both arguments.

```
public static void testImplementation(Test.MyInterface impl) {
    makeTest(new Test.TestClass1(), impl);
    makeTest(new Test.TestClass2(1, "ABC"), impl);
    //...
```

This presents a contradiction. In the first case T will be `TestClass1`, in the second it will be `TestClass2`. If you were to use the generic version of `Test.MyInterface`, there is no type that can possibly satisfy it. You're only getting away with this because you're using raw types. It can't be `Test.MyInterface<TestClass1>` and `Test.MyInterface<TestClass2>` simultaneously.

You need to get rid of the `testImplementation` method and stop using raw types. The first part of your main method might look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    makeTest(new Test.TestClass1(), new Test.MyClass<>());
    makeTest(new Test.TestClass2(1, "ABC"), new Test.MyClass<>());
```

Comment: The method `testImplementation()` is unavoidable because it combines a bunch of tests for a particular `MyInterface` implementation and outputs the final result at the end. What if I needed to conduct 10 tests for 10 different implementations? Insert 100 `makeTest()` calls into `main()`?

Comment: I mentioned using the `<?>` wildcard in the question. Maybe `testImplementation(MyInterface<?> impl)` would be a better signature of the method?

Comment: That doesn't solve the fact that it's a logical contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've solved it.

```
/* This utility method bears the brunt.
 * It shows that the cast is safe for this particular interface.
 * It is recommended to explain why. Example is given below. */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> MyInterface<T> reify(MyInterface<?> impl) {
    /* Safe because instances of MyInterface<T> doesn't suppose to hold
     * objects of type T (directly or indirectly) between invocations
     * of its methods. */
    return (MyInterface<T>) impl;
}

// Use a wildcard type in the signature
public static void testImplementation(MyInterface<?> impl) {
    // No warnings now
    makeTest(new TestClass1(), reify(impl));
    makeTest(new TestClass2(1, "ABC"), reify(impl));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Use the diamond operator for ordinary classes
    testImplementation(new MyClass<>());
    // Use lambda expressions when possible
    testImplementation(x -> x);
    /* Anonymous classes still require explicit type
    (Object in this case, Bound when the type variable is bounded
    at the interface definition: MyInterface<T extends Bound> */
    testImplementation(new MyInterface<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object method(Object input) {
            return input;
        }
    });
}
```

Still requires one `@SuppressWarnings` but concentrates all unsafe operations in one place where it is to be explained why the suppression is safe.

If someone has got a better solution please let me know.